# Drop down list that covers two correspoding columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a calcuation worksheet for pricing construction materials, which i need to be easy to use, quick and accurate.

Can a drop down list (let say the list is in cell A1) choose from a range of values in column C10-B200, but then ALSO bring in the equivalent value from the range D10-B200.

IE, if a user chooses "C17" from the list in cell A1, i want cell B1 to automatically contain the value from "D17".

Do i use an if function, or can a list simply span two columns? I have used data validation to create a 'materials' drop down list, but need this to also include the 'price', if you see what i mean.

Any help appreciated, thanks
Euan

Comment: You'll want to investigate the DLOOPKUP() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Put this formula in the adjacent cell.

```
=IF(B3<>"";INDEX(G3:G12;MATCH(B3;F3:F12);0);"")
```

Where

- B3 contains the dropdown (validation list =F3:F12)
- C3 contains the formula given above
- F3:F12 contains the texts displayed in the dropdown
- G3:G12 contains the values to display in the second cell

[image]